# lodash compare elements in one array

Tags: arrays, compare, lodash

I have an array whose elements are {id:"id",display:"displaytext"}. I want to compare elements of it and if display value is same, I have to concat the id's and have only one element instead of 2 in the array.

eg: arr[{id:"id1", display:"text display"},{id:"id2",display:"text display"}]
arr now should be,
arr[{id:"id1, id2", display:"text display"}]

I see on lodash some functions where we can compare only 2 arrays. I am using 4.13.1 lodash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`lodash#groupBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#groupBy) and [`lodash#map`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map) to achieve this.

```
var result = _(array)
  .groupBy('display')
  .map(function(group) {
    return {
      id: _.map(group, 'id').join(', '),
      display: group[0].display
    };
  }).value();
```

```js
var array = [{
  id: "id1",
  display: "text display"
}, {
  id: "id2",
  display: "text display"
}];

var result = _(array)
  .groupBy('display')
  .map(function(group) {
    return {
      id: _.map(group, 'id').join(', '),
      display: group[0].display
    };
  }).value();
  
console.log(result);
```

```css
body > div {min-height: 100%; top: 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```